# Oracle create user doesn't respond

Tags: oracle11g

I'm working on a clean installation of Oracle 11g, I access in sqlplus as sysdba.
If I type

```
CREATE USER demo1 
IDENTIFIED BY demo1 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE demo1 
QUOTA 10M ON demo1 
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp 
QUOTA 5M ON system;
```

sql remain in waiting utill i press CTRL+C.

Is there some checks can i perform? or are there some prerequisites for create the new user?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me on 11gXE (I've adjusted tablespace names, though):

```
SQL> select * From v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user demo1
  2  identified by demo1
  3  default tablespace users
  4  quota 10m on users
  5  temporary tablespace temp
  6  quota 5m on system;

User created.

SQL>
```

So, you are saying that - when you typed the semi-colon at the end of line 6 (in my code) and pressed the `ENTER` key, nothing happens?

Comment: I confirm "when you typed the semi-colon at the end of line 6 (in my code) and pressed the ENTER key, nothing happens?" Nothing happens and I need to press CTRL+C to exit

Comment: Hm. Strange. This probably won't help, but - try to type slash `/` and hit ENTER again.

Comment: This is the result "SQL> CREATE USER demo1 IDENTIFIED BY demo1 DEFAULT TABLESPACE demo1 QUOTA 10M ON demo1 TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp QUOTA 5M ON system;
/    " Also after the / nothing happens. I think that something was wrong during the oracle installation but I don't know what